# Restrict global color transition on certain elements

Tags: css, css-transitions

Hello I am using the global code for transition color

```
* {
    transition: color 0.6s ease 0s;
}
```

and I don't want it to be active on the hover state on the main menu tabs labeled HOME, MYTEAM, GAMEDAY, etc.

website
http://www51.myfantasyleague.com/2017/home/36888#0

When I add transition none, it doesn't work.

```
.myfantasyleague_tabmenu #homepagetabs li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(218, 54, 54, 0.7);
    box-shadow: none;transition:none;
}
```

I must not have the correct code to stop the transition color on the tabs, can you please help me there.
Thx

Comment: When `transition: none` is applied to the `:hover` state, it means that the transition *from* the hover state *to* the ground state is removed. If you want to stop the `<li>` from transitioning to the `:hover` state instead, apply `transition: none` onto the selector without the pseudo-selector (i.e. `.myfantasyleague_tabmenu #homepagetabs li {...}`). It helps to think that `transition` works to specify transitions away from the current state of the selector.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the transition on the element and not in the hover..

```
.myfantasyleague_tabmenu #homepagetabs li{
   -webkit-transition-property: none;
-moz-transition-property: none;
-o-transition-property: none;
transition-property: none;
}
```

I suggest not using the * selector to set the transition... , because it will set to all the elements.. A better way would be applying in to a class an using it where is needed

Comment: So I agree the global transition should be removed and applied to only elements of my choice. For an example the top menu>>REPORTS>>FRANCHISEPLAYER on hover it displays nice a red color then fades back to white once you move off the element. If I remove the global transition, it don't fade back to white, rather a hard hit of the white color is displayed. What code do I add to this element, to make it the same effect as the global element transition code?     .myfantasyleague_menu ul li ul li:hover > a {

}

Answer (score 0):

You must put the `transition: none` to your `li` but not in the `:hover` state:

```
.myfantasyleague_tabmenu #homepagetabs li {
    /* other css*/
    transition: none;
}
```